# Customizing XmlSerialization in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

In WCF services, can't migrate to `DataContract Serialization` right now. I need to control xml-serialization default behavior.

Here are my POCO classes, on which I need to grab full control over serialization process.

```
[Serializable]
public class ProductBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class DurableProduct : ProductBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Price Pricing { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Price : IXmlSerializable
{
    public int Monthly { get; set; }
    public int Annual { get; set; }
}
```

I need control over serialization process of classes `DurableProduct`, `Price`. Thus I have implemented `IXmlSerializable` on these classes as below -

```
[Serializable]
public class DurableProduct : ProductBase, IXmlSerializable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Price Pricing { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        Id = int.Parse(reader.ReadElementString());
        Name = reader.ReadElementString();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("Id", Id.ToString());
        writer.WriteElementString("Name", Name);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Id : {0}, Name: {1}, Monthly: {2}", Id, Name, Pricing.Monthly);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Price : IXmlSerializable
{
    public int Monthly { get; set; }
    public int Annual { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        //Control never reaches here, while deserializing DurableProduct
        Monthly = int.Parse(reader.ReadElementString());
        Annual = int.Parse(reader.ReadElementString());
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        //Control never reaches here, while deserializing DurableProduct
        writer.WriteElementString("MyCustomElement1", Monthly.ToString());
        writer.WriteElementString("MyCustomElement2", Annual.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Problem** When I attempt to serialize/deserialize there classes `IXmlSerializable => ReadXml / WriteXml` are not being called.

> How Do I implement my classes so that all the Read/Write
>   implementations of IXmlSerializable is invoked reliably.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to decorate your operation contract with theses attributes :

```
[OperationContract(Action = "urn:yourActionNamesapce", ReplyAction = "urn:yourReplyActionNamesapce")]
[XmlSerializerFormat()]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ProductBase))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(DurableProduct))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Price))]
YourResponse YourOperation(DurableProduct request);
```

Then, you only have to pass your POCO to the client, when you call your web service.

```
DurableProduct request = ...
using (YourClient client = new YourClient())
{
    client.YourOperation(request);
}
```